# CakePHP [.htaccess], static files as the root of project

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I would like to be able to access static files at the root of my project, in a folder at the same level of app/. It's because that is the only directory to wich I have the permission to read-write files on my server, so our images are uploaded there.

So if someone writes this URL:

> www.mysite.com/img-rw

It displays images in the folder at [project-root]/my-rw-dir

Any ideas on how to edit .htaccess files for something like this to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way? Can't you set permissions to a folder within `webroot`, such as `/app/webroot/my-wr-dir`? This way you wouldn't need to change your `.htaccess` and you wouldn't be opening security flaws in your project.

Comment: I will try, but this setup is a requirement for a course project and it is the the same for all students, only our setup would be different because of CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this works great :

.htaccess (project root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # This folder is a subfolder of project root but contains static images
    # Accessed like so:  www.mysite.com/imgrw/[file name]
    RewriteRule ^imgrw/(.*)$ /dir-at-root-level/img/$1 [L]

    # Everything else is handled by cakephp webroot
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(dir-at-root-level) [NC]
    RewriteRule    ^(.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: in my webroot img folder, I can access image directly like www.mydomain.com/app/webroot/img/equipment/photo1_136810827.jpeg               is there a way to prevent it ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that **this is a course project** (as the OP said in comments) and you **are NOT concerned about security flaws**, here is what you could do.

By default CakePHP has 3 nested `.htaccess` files:

1. `/.htaccess` (Project root folder)
2. `/app/.htaccess`
3. `/app/webroot/.htaccess`

The first (topmost) of them is the first to respond when you try to access www.mysite.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Clearly, this sends the user request right into the `/app/webroot` folder. We could use the conditional check that exists in `/app/webroot/.htacess` to, instead of promptly redirecting to `webroot`, check if the given URL matches to a file or folder. In order to do so, you'll need to update the parent (`/.htaccess`) file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Checks if the given URL matches to a folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Checks if the given URL matches to a file
  #RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] # This line is commented, should be removed
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This way, the request will only be redirected to /app/webroot if **none of the conditions are met**. If you need only to return files, than you could remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, which verifies if the URL matches to a folder ( `-d` = directory).

A cleaner version that would only check for files should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

With this tweak, accessing www.mysite.com/image.jpg should return the file `image.jpg` hosted at your project root (`/image.jpg`).

Comment: Thanks for this well writen response. However, do you think it would be possible to create a condition that only redirect to a subfolder of the project root when the URL matches /img-wr? Given that the project may become public.

Comment: Mmmhh could you explain a little further, with examples maybe? I'm not sure I've understand it completely. Do you want to redirect `mysite.com/urlfolder/file.jpg` to `/first-level-folder/file.jpg`?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant